# Solve the equation $z^{4} + (1-i)z^{2} - i = 0$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, factoring

The proposed equation is given by:

$$z^{4} + (1-i)z^{2} - i = 0$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

I tried to start solving it like this:

\begin{align*}
(a+bi)^4 + (i - 1)(a + bi)^2 -i = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow a^4 + 4a^3bi - 6a^2b^2 - 4ab^3i + b^4 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow a^4 + b^4 = 2ab(3ab + 2b^2i - 2a^2i)
\end{align*}

But I couldn't do it further.

Comment: Set $Z=z^2$, then you'll have a second order equation...

Comment: This quartic is actually a quadratic in $z^2$ which you can solve immediately by formula. After that, the trick is to simplify, take the square roots to find $z$ and simplify some more. There's no need to write $z = a+bi$ right at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Here it is an alternative way to solve it for the sake of curiosity.

\begin{align*}
z^{4} + (1-i)z^{2} - i = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow (z^{4} + z^{2}) - i(z^{2} + 1) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z^{2}(z^{2} + 1) - i(z^{2} + 1) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (z^{2} - i)(z^{2} + 1) = 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: as I undesrtood, roots of (z^2 + 1) = 0 are ±1. But I'm not sure about (z^2 - i) = 0, are the roots ±√i?

Comment: The roots of $z^{2} + 1 = 0$ are $\pm i$. To obtain the roots of $z^{2} - i = 0$, you can express $i = \cos(\pi/2) + i\sin(\pi/2)$ and apply the DeMoivre's formula. Can you take it from here?